# How can I write if and else statement in twig

Tags: symfony

I want to make an if statement in twig.
I have this html:

```
  <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><input id="price" data-slider-id='priceSlider' type="text"
                                                             data-slider-min="10000" data-slider-max="50000"
                                                             data-slider-step="2000" data-slider-value="{{ app.request.get('price') }}"
                                                             data-slider-handle="square"/></td>
```

I want to write something like this:

```
if({{ app.request.get('price') }})  data-slider-value="{{ app.request.get('price') }}"
else  data-slider-value="10000"
```

How can I do this in twig?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
data-slider-value="{{ app.request.get('price') is defined  ? app.request.get('price'):"10000" }}"
```

[twig defined](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if app.request.get('price') is defined %} 
    data-slider-value="{{ app.request.get('price') }}"
{% else %} 
    data-slider-value="10000" 
{% endif %}
```

[twig if-else documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding 3rd variant:

```
{% set sliderVal = app.request.get('price') is defined ? app.request.get('price') : 10000 %}
data-slider-value="{{ sliderVal }}"
```